# Delphi - Hide Window By its Title

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm looking for a code that can hide the window (visibility = false ) by its title.  (and i'm not looking for killing task)
I've already a code that brings me handle parent, then I can send a `Showwindow(number of handle,  sw_hide);` to the external application.

but now i'm searching for something faster ...

I've a code that can kill a window by its title : if we can modify it to hide the window it will be good.

```
begin
    PID := FindProcessByTitle('Form1');
    if PID <> 0 then
       begin hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, PID);

    if hProcess <> 0 then begin TerminateProcess(hProcess,0); CloseHandle(hProcess);

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple. Take the following steps:

1. Use `FindWindow` or `FindWindowEx` or `EnumerateWindows` to locate your window.
2. Use `ShowWindow` to hide the window.

You already know about `ShowWindow` so presumably the problem is with item 1. But then again you apparently already know how to obtain a PID from a window title which would imply that you have, as part of that process, been able to find the window handle.

So, take your existing code and modify `FindProcessByTitle` to return a window handle rather than the PID.

You also mention that you want your code to run faster. The process described above should execute extremely quickly. If your code is slow, we can't really advise on how to improve its speed (if indeed that is possible) without sight of the actual code.

In short, I should probably not have answered the question in its current form, and instead asked that you improve the question first.

Comment: I'm not looking for hiding window . i'm lookin' for HIDING WINDOW Please . thank's . if you can give a code. that will be great.

Comment: `ShowWindow` is how you hide windows. Have you considered hiring a programmer to write code for you. Stack Overflow is not a site where you get people to do your programming for free. If you already have a programmer, why not ask them to write the code? If you have code that is not working, show a [mcve] and ask for specific help in understanding what is wrong. I see that you are new to SO, perhaps a trip to the [help] would be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much , don't get nervous. i just said if someone can post us a code it will be great. that's all

Comment: @JohnBaker, `"I'm not looking for hiding window . i'm lookin' for HIDING WINDOW"` - Can you explain this?

Comment: i said "i'm not looking for a code that kill task, looking for a code that hide window by its title".

Comment: @JohnBaker: No, [you said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121328/delphi-hide-window-by-its-title#comment65588516_39121455) *I'm not looking for hiding window . i'm lookin' for HIDING WINDOW*, which makes  no sense.

Comment: I improved the answer , If you can answer the question in its current form please it will be great , i mean a real code for testing.

Comment: @John You improved your question, not the answer. And actually you barely did anything. I'm also very lost what you meant by "`I'm not looking for hiding window . i'm lookin' for HIDING WINDOW`" It's no different than saying "I don't want a beer, I want a beer."

Comment: John, you're not getting any code here because you already have the code. You have whatever code is in FindProcessByTitle, and you've been told you can adapt it to find the window handle instead. You already know how to hide a window. Which part do you still think you need? If you're not willing to read and write code yourself, then Stack Overflow is not for you; it's a site for programmers, and that's what programmers do. If you need help adapting the window-finding code, then say so, but also share that code and explain which part you don't understand so that someone can help you.